# Prestashop Display my own carrier

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a module to display two carriers, this carriers install it but i dont want to do it, be cause first i want validate a postcode but from my database not directly from prestashop, if the postcode is in my database the carriers display but if the postcode is not in my db not display my carriers.

Is necessary to use a `hook` or use `_getCarrierList` function to do that i want?

If is necessary use `_getCarrierList` can explain me be cause i dont know how can use the function.

I follow this module example to create my carriers ([Carrier modules: functions, creation and configuration](https://www.prestashop.com/blog/en/carrier_modules_functions_creation_and_configuration/))